# In a general sense, how would you make multiple argparse arguments that run a CLI app in different ways?

Tags: python, argparse

let us say you have the following optional arguments: "default [-d], test [-t], and advanced [-a]".

Without putting any arguments, the CLI app would run on default [-d] whether you say [-d] or not. but what if I wanted for the other two arguments,[-t] and [-d]. for each one of them, if you put one of them, they would run the program in two different ways.

In a general sense on how to code that. would I define all of the arguments at once, or do I do so within a function that would define how the different options would run the program?

Exampele if I want to run the program on [-a], do I define that up top and then reference it somehow in the function that defines that certain path the program could take? Or do I define it somehow directly in that function?

Can you perhaps provide me with links to code that I can look at and learn from? Perhaps a name for having multiple arguments that which of arg would run the program in different ways so that i can further research?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#sub-commands

Comment: It's not clear whether you don't know how to set up and use `argparse`, or are unclear as to how to use the results, the `args` Namespace.  In the simplest case `args.test`, `args.default` etc are just string values.  You just use a set of `if/else` statements to run the desired function.  For more help you will need to give sample code.